# How to show a footnote in docx?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

In my *XWPFDocument* I have inserted various footnotes and they are stored in a `List<XWPFFootnote>` inside it. Here is an example of one of my footnotes from the *XWPFDocument* (in XML):

```xml
<w:footnote w:id="4">
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Helvetica" w:hAnsi="Helvetica"/>
        <w:sz w:val="14"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="14"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>Esto es un epígrafe.</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
```

I can get them easily by id with `doc.getFootnoteByID(id)` and it returns them correctly. However, I don't really know how to show them visually in my document, because right now they are in the *XWPFDocument* but I can't find a way to "append them" or something like that into a a document page, *XWPFParagraph* or *XWPFRun*. I have also tried with *HeaderFooterPolicy* but it doesn't seem to work with *XWPFFootnote* or its *CTFtnEd*n property either.

To be clear, doing this for example:

```java
XWPFTable table = paragraph.getBody().insertNewTbl(cursor);
XWPFTableRow row = table.createRow();
XWPFTableCell cell= row.addNewTableCell();
p = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
r = p.createRun();
r.setText(this.getMsg().getProperty("TEXT"));
```

My goal is to show the w:id as a superscript of 'TEXT', and then the "definition" at the end of the page. I have tried to find a way to do that, but I haven't had luck.

I was wondering how can I make them appear just like a classic footnote (the id in the text, the definition at the end) in the docx, I can't seem to find a method.

I hope it's a valid question. Thank you.